# get selected value in an auto populated drop down

Tags: php, html

I would like to know how we can store the value selected in an auto populated drop down (HTML5) into a variable, all in PHP. I want to obtain this value BEFORE clicking the 'Submit' button.

```
<?php
    $i=1;
    $j=0;
    $result=pg_exec($pgsql_conn,"select * from crm.product_info order by 1");
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {
?>
<td><input type="checkbox" 
        id= <?php 
                echo $row['product_id'];
            ?> 
        value= <?php
                    echo $i; 
                ?> 
        name= "prod[]"> &nbsp; 
            <?php echo $row['product_name']; ?>
    </td>
<td>
    <input type="button" value=<?php echo "$".$row['product_value']; ?> id="but">
</td>
<td>
    Quantity&nbsp; 
    <select class="select" name="qty[]">
        <?php echo "qty".$j; ?>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    Amount 
    <input 
        id="amt" 
        type="text" 
        readonly 
        value=<?php 
            echo $row['product_value']
        ?> >
</td>

<?php
    }
?>
```

I require the SELECTED value of 'quantity'.

This is how i auto populate the quantity. It is from 0-100.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
    {
        $(".select").append("<option value=\""+i+"\">"+i+"</option>");
    }    
});
```

Comment: What do you want to acheive ? In your code you don't even add options to your select element ! `<select class="select" name="qty[]"><?php echo "qty".$j; ?></select>` is not the right way to set a value to the select.

Comment: Does the edit answer your question?

Comment: `<input type="checkbox"` is not closed. Are you sure this code is working

Comment: What is your goal? getting a client side variable in php (which is server side) is not possible. you could push it to the server with ajax though, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, PHP is server side, so it can't handle changes made in the browser until a request is send to it. You will have to use javascript to know selected value in real time before submitting the form. You can manipulate this value using javascript. But if you really need to do some PHP with the selected value, your solution is to use Ajax for this.